# using cloud code plugin for GCP (google cloud platform)

Tags: intellij-idea, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-code

I've a local clusters (minikube) that work pefectly well on my laptop (mint 19.3, Intellij 2019.3 with cloud code plugin, java (11) backend, mongo db, front end, .. ok ). But I can't find any usefull informations (on google cloud plateform site or intellij) to configure a new google cloud cluster. I can only see my minikube conf on the cluster explorer...even when I stopped minikube !

It seems that configuration could be found in kubctl !? But how can I force plugin to connect GCP. I've a GCP account and created a cluster and an image repo.

GCP documentation looks really unclear.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. You need to install SDK cloud ( an other solution ?), an use gcloud instructions to link kubctl with new kubernetes context, and for credentials contexts. a new configuration for kubctl must be generated, and you have to switch to that configuration (kubectl config set your-new-cluster).

Just one thing, to use google storage for docker images, you should enter where to find or put it in the conf of the run/edit configuration line image options -> gcr.io/your-project-id . I couldn't use the bucket i created before pushing, a new one was created. Is there a solution to connect with an existing bucket ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manage your clusters from an on-prem machine you will need to [install Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-access-for-kubectl#overview) and configure your cluster access, this will allow you to use kubectl comands to create, and administrate the clusters on GKE. Cloud code plugin should install this SDK automatically, you can take a look to [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/code/docs/intellij/quickstart-IDEA) to learn hoy to use it.